# Setting the height of iframe Tabs for Facebook profile Pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-iframe

As we know that Facebook has introduced [iframe Tabs for Pages](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/462). I have developed an application and added the tab of the application in a profile page, application tab is opened in an iframe according to the update "iframe Tabs for Pages". The problem is that height of the page is not adjusted and unable to remove the scrollbars to display the fully page without scrollbars. All the solutions which I found work for the Application canvas page but not for the Application Tab page.

How can we do that?

Answer (score 21):

It's quite easy to achieve. You have to set up the application in the Facebook Integration tab as an **IFRAME** and the size of the frame as **"Auto-resize".**

Now, on your server, you have to add the following code before the `</BODY>` tag:

```html
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    FB.Canvas.setSize();
</script>
```

This will auto resize it. It also helps if you add **overflow:hidden** to the BODY tag.

Comment: FYI: I had to use an explicit size like: "FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 520, height: 620 });".
Don't forget to read the documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setSize/

Answer (score 14):

The following guide helped me through the same problem:

http://www.hyperarts.com/blog/facebook-iframe-apps-getting-rid-of-scrollbars/

In short, do the following:

- **Change your "IFrame Size" to "Auto-resize"**
- **Load Facebook's Javascript SDK**

add the following code just before the `</body>` tag of your index page:

```html
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script>
FB.init({
appId : 'YOUR-APP-ID-HERE',
status : true, // check login status
cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
xfbml : true // parse XFBML
});
</script>
```

- **Use FB.Canvas.setSize()**

Put the following code before the `</head>` tag:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.Canvas.setSize();
}
// Do things that will sometimes call sizeChangeCallback()
function sizeChangeCallback() {
FB.Canvas.setSize();
}
</script>
```

That should do it, hope it helps!

Answer (score 9):

facebook recently changed something, now your tab file also needs the `fb.init` method. otherwise the resize wont work. so use this in your tab page as well

```html
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() 
{
    FB.init({ appId: 'YOUR APP ID', 
    status: true, 
    cookie: true,
    xfbml: true,
    oauth: true});

    FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();
    FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
}
    </script>
```

Comment: This sorted it for me, I just needed to add the two FB.Canvas method calls as listed above.

Comment: setAutoGrow is the new name for setAutoResize. Having both is not necessary.

Comment: This worked a charm. I hate that Facebook keeps changing things and letting out of date documentation roam free in the wild.

Answer (score 6):

**Updated code** for everyone having issues:

1) Set your application "Canvas Height" to "Fluid".

2) Copy + paste the following code before the closing <body> tag.

```html
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Called when FB SDK has been loaded
  window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    // Initialize the FB javascript SDK
    FB.init({
      appId: '[YOUR APP ID]',
      status: true,
      cookie: true,
      xfbml: true
    });

    // Auto resize FB Canvas
    FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
  };

  // Load the FB SDK Asynchronously
  (function (d) {
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
  } (document));

</script>
```

Comment: I tried a combination of the code provided by Gergely Varga (directly above this comment) AND changing the javascript library to 1.5.1. Poifect.

Answer (score 2):

Hey guys... I was having problems with it as well.. i have tried a myriad of solutions and suggestions and they never worked for me. After I changed the jquery library 1.6 to the 1.5.1 it worked. Check if that is your problem.

Now I am trying to know why the hell it does not work with the version 1.6 of jquery.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone like me who tried all of the above to no avail, here's what finally worked for me. Taken from this page: https://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=10150149060995844

Before `</head>` :

```html
<script type="text/javascript">

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {

FB.Canvas.setSize({ height: 'HEIGHT YOU WANT', width: 'WIDTH YOU WANT' });

}

// Do things that will sometimes call sizeChangeCallback()

function sizeChangeCallback() {

FB.Canvas.setSize({ height: 'HEIGHT YOU WANT', width: 'WIDTH YOU WANT' });

}

</script>
```

Then before `</body>`:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">

                FB.init({
                    appId: 'XXXXXXXXXXX', //Your facebook APP here
                    status: true, // check login status
                    cookie: true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
                    xfbml: true// parse XFBML
                });

        </script>
```