# Can I set the Page Tab height on a Facebook app?

Tags: facebook

I have created a Facebook Page Tab app using the [Heroku hosting option](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/facebook). I see an option for setting the width of the Page Tab to either Normal (810px) or Narrow (520px), but don't see an option to set the height, as there is when creating an 'App on Facebook' app.

I understand I could set this app up as an 'App on Facebook', but am wondering if I might be missing something in the 'Page Tab' app setup.

Here is a [screenshot](https://dzwonsemrish7.cloudfront.net/items/433W3l0A2k2d0U2F301E/Screenshot_12_29_12_4_27_PM-2.png?v=d3dcc75d) of the 'App on Facebook' and 'Page Tab' app setup page.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here's what worked, based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/13181388/820113

```
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() 
{
    FB.init({ appId: 'appid', 
    status: true, 
    cookie: true,
    xfbml: true,
    oauth: true});

    FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
}
</script>
```

And a `<div id="fb-root"></div>` in the body.

Answer (score 6):

Found latest solution @ Step 2014

What you need to do

After  add this:

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '{Your-mail-App_id}',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.0'
    });
      FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 770, height: 735 }); // set your own figure
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

That is all. It will work for sure.
FB.Canvas.setSize() without parameters means leting FB auto detect page size.

Answer (score 2):

Insert before you close the body tag:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init();
        FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
    }
</script>
```