# Facebook how to set height for facebook page tab app?

Tags: facebook

How to set the height for a Facebook tab app.

I can see it is possible to set the height and width on a Facebook app.

But under settings it is only possible to set the width for a facebook tab app:
Page Tab Width:

How do I set the height for a page tab(app)?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.setSize/

Comment: Look at this, also

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14086142/can-i-set-the-page-tab-height-on-a-facebook-app

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to set a default size `setSize()`,
if you have dynamic height content, you can use `setDoneLoading()` and after page load you can run the `setAutoGrow()` inside the callback.

```
FB.Canvas.setSize({ width: 810, height: 950 });

FB.Canvas.setDoneLoading( function(response) {
    FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow();
});
```